# Tolerate . and [^...] in /RegExp/

Tags: javascript, jslint

It seems that JSlint recently added the option:

"Tolerate . and [^...] in /RegExp/".

Why would using `.` or `^` in regular expressions be bad?

Comment: You have to remember that JSLint is *very* aggressive about what it views as bad practice. Crockford basically believes that if there's any chance of introducing bugs with some language feature, it shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: So what then? You're supposed to escape it even when it's inside the character set, or are you supposed to throw it outside and do some `(\.|[abc])` garbage? I don't see how this could introduce errors, unless you don't know regular expressions and are confused as to it's meaning when inside a set...but then you just need to brush up on your regexes, that's not lint's job to tell you you don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis: from that perspective, no computer languages should be allowed at all. And no computers in general. And no mechanisms for that matter. And no... What the heck, the humans should not be allowed!

Comment: @FyodorSoikin and Mark: That was, rather, my point: JSLint is *too* aggressive about that sort of thing; you should not take its rules as gospel. I personally disagree with it and am just pointing out what I see as the philosophy behind JSLint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the JSLint documentation](http://www.jslint.com/lint.html):

> They match more material than might be expected, allowing attackers to confuse applications. These forms should not be used when validating in secure applications.

This appears to be based on a philosophy of being specific about what you allow instead of allowing anything (including multibyte and non-printing characters) with `.` or allowing anything except x, y and z (as `[^…]` means)

From [the JSLint mailing list](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/message/1377):

> The rationale behind this is that some people don't understand what `.`
>   and `[^...]` mean in regular expressions, so it causes their code to either accept
>   something as valid when it isn't, or reject something that's valid.

Comment: The use of `^` inside character classes seems particularly mis-understood.